# Window snapping changes in Tweak Tool not taking effect

Tags: unity, compiz, 14.04, unity-tweak-tool

I'm trying to change the window snapping behavior in Unity (14.04) using the Tweak Tool.  The Window Snapping section of the tool is available, and all the options are available (not greyed out).  I make the changes I want, but the actual snapping behavior doesn't change.  For instance, I set the bottom screen edge to "Bottom Half", and then drag a window to the bottom edge and nothing happens.  Closing the tweak tool, logging out and back in, and even restarting the whole computer don't help.  After making a change, if I close and then reopen the Tweak Tool, the change persists.  It's simply not reflected in the actual snapping behavior.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted this on Ubuntu Forums and got a good workaround (Use CCSM instead of Tweak Tool). Details can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224514)

EDIT (Copy instructions from linked page):

1. Install CCSM

   From terminal: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
   Or you can install it from the Software Center
2. Open it up and go to: Window Management → Grid
3. Then click on the "Corners / Edges" tab and configure away.

Comment: I'm not sure why my reward for linking to an answer I got on another site was 2 downvotes.  I could have not bothered to link anything at all, and would have had a higher reputation at the end of it all.  Interesting culture you have here at this site.

Comment: See [How do I write a good answer?: Provide context for links](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer). :) Never mind about few downvote (just -2 each) where upvote is (+10 each). BTW, the downvoter gets -1. So If he care, he may get back to it and change his vote after edit. See https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @Sneetsher thanks for the clarification and helpful meta-links.